# JavaScriptSerializer is not allowed in .net core project?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, jsonserializer, json-serialization

I am working in .net core project. I want to serialize the objects using JavaScriptSerializer.

```
JavaScriptSerializer Serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

I added the namespace `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`. It throws errors. I googled it. I saw like .net core project does not have `System.Web.Script.Serialization;` in some sites.

Is there have any another way to serialize the objects in the .net core like JavaScriptSerializer?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In .net core the most common way of serializing and deserializing objects (JSON) using Newtonsoft.Json.

You need to install the Nuget Package of [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

add using a statement like:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

and use it as:

```
object o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json1);
string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: How-to convert string (format json) to List<string>: `{"result":["PRE_VPN_Usuarios","PRE_Usuarios COMUNICADOS MAD","PRE_Campaña Agentes MAD"]}`

Answer (score 21):

For **ASP.NET Core 3.1** we can use [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=netcore-3.1) from [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1) with a `string`/`dynamic` dictionary `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`.

Example loading `ClientApp\package.json`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

var packageJson = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp", "package.json"));

var packageInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(packageJson);

Console.WriteLine("SPA Name: {0}, SPA Version: {1}", 
    packageInfo["name"], packageInfo["version"]);
```

Of course we'll have to copy `ClientApp\package.json` to the publish directory using a `Target` > `Copy` command inside `.csproj`.

Comment: this almost works, but nested elements are of type `JsonElement` instead of `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` and can't be indexed by strings.

Comment: @DaveCousineau indeed, good point; this is mostly for quick access to flat level properties; for more complex cases and when we need to access nested elements, I believe it's better to create a proper interface/class and use that as a generic for the deserializer.

Answer (score 4):

Install Newtonsoft.Json and then

in Controller:

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { MyUser = user, MyId = id });
object dataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
return Json(dataObj);
```

and in Javascript file:

```
$.ajax({
   // some codes!
   success: function(data){
      var user = data.MyUser;
      var id = data.MyId
   }
});
```

Comment: What is `Json(dataObj)` ?